# shell script - trying not to use tmp files

Tags: bash, shell

How can I do that without tmp1 and tmp2?
(information files are good)

```
      cat information_file1 | sed -e 's/\,/\ /g' >> tmp1
      echo Messi >> tmp2
      cat tmp1 | grep Ronaldo  | cut -d"=" -f2- >> tmp2
      rm tmp1
      cat information_file2 | fin_func tmp2
      rm tmp2
```

fin_func for your insight.(its not really the func and I dont want to change it just that you will see how I use tmp2 and info_file2)

```
while read -a line; do

if [[ "`grep $line $1`" != "" ]]; then
echo 1
fi

done
```

Comment: What is fin_func and can it take its input from a pipe/stdin rather than take a file name and reading from there?

Comment: fin_func its a function who gets input(info_file2 with while read) and use also tmp2 as parametr($1 - for example do in fin_func grep $1...)

Comment: You know that `grep` won’t be executed? It’s just a string and misses `\`…\`` or `$(…)` if you want it being executed.

Comment: You’re also missing a `; do` after `while read -a line` and a `;` between `]]` and `then`.

Comment: if you are talking about fin_func I wrote there that its not the real func. Its from my imagination just for your insight. my func works fine and its a little bigger than that func.
I just need a way to minimize the lines above to 1 line and without tmo files(tmp 1 and tmp2)

Comment: Rather than `[[` and comparing the output of `grep` to the empty string, you want `if grep -q "$line" $1; then`

Answer (score 1):

This should work, although it’s pretty incomprehensive:

```
cat information_file2 | fin_func <(cat <(echo Messi) <(cat information_file1 | \
  sed -e 's/\,/\ /g' | grep Ronaldo | cut -d"=" -f2-))
```

The `<( … )` syntax is [Bash’s process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), which returns a the name of a file `/dev/fd` file descriptor and whose output it written to.

Comment: didn't work. I think cause in my code tmp2 is a paramter and in fin_func I use it as $1. here its just regular input.
remember its not bash, its sh.

Comment: @KobiGuetta So Bourne Shell or which shell?

Comment: its #!/bin/sh. so I think its regular shell

Comment: @KobiGuetta What does `/bin/sh --version` print?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: @KobiGuetta So it *is* Bash.

Comment: strange, cause I tried something that bash has, and it didnt work.
I cant remeber what I have tried.
anyway can you help with that one?
I edited the question up

Comment: @KobiGuetta It should be noted that the process substitution creates a fifo file that you can only read once from, similar to a pipe between processes.

Comment: I didnt understand.
can you find me a solution? even with 1 tmp file(its better than 2)

Comment: @KobiGuetta, @Gumbo: While it is `bash,` it is running in _POSIX compatibility mode_ due to having been invoked as `sh`, in which case process substitution is not supported. Thus, try again with shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` - see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Answer (score 0):

The sample `fin_func` reads through the file given as a command argument multiple times, so unless we are allowed to modify that function at least one temporary file will be necessary.  The sample `fin_func` given in the question can be easily modified so that it does not read the file multiple times, but since you indicate that this is not the real script I will assume it cannot be modified and must take a file as an argument.  That said, I would write your script as:

```
trap 'rm -f $TMPFILE' 0  # in bash, just trapping on 0 will work for SIGINT, etc 
TMPFILE=$( mktemp ) 

{ echo Messi
tr , ' '  < information_file1 | 
awk -F= '/Ronaldo/{print $2}' ; } > $TMPFILE
< information_file2 fin_func $TMPFILE
```

I strongly suspect that `fin_func` could be rewritten so that it does not require a regular file as input.  Also, there's no need for the `tr`, as you could `gsub` in `awk` only on matching lines and save a bit of processing, but that is probably a trivial optimization.  However, using `tr` instead of `sed` is aesthetically necessary.